# How works apply method for python pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

How works apply method for python pandas dataframes? It works in parallel? If the last answer is no, how can I parallelize to improve my process??

Comment: I think that depends on the underlying numpy operations, which should be parallelized.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html

Comment: `apply` is syntactic sugar for looping row/column-wise it isn't vectorised. It should be last resort as there are very few operations that cannot be vectorised

Comment: No. It is a wrapper around a plain for-loop.

Comment: @ballpointben `numpy` operations aren't parallelized by default.

Comment: Thanks to all. Specially to @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ for the link. I think it could be very useful, but now I m' doing a more complex operations in a Machine Learning process for text classification (using model prediction functions, regular expressions or single string operations) so these _magic_ tools like `numba`, `cython` or `df.eval` can't help me now. So I think I must use something like `multiprocessing` package for parallelize with `Pool`. Any recommendation?